# Open ViewPager2 to particular position without scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

I have implemented a recyclerview with some videos *(say 10)*. Clicking on any item opens a `viewpager2 which is on some other activity` with all the items *`and`* the clicked one (from `recyclerview`) is shown. After that user can scroll to other item from there only. Everything is working fine.

**Only the problem is with the scrolling when recyclerview item click where is the viewpager2 is opened.**

Whenever any item is selected(10th). The viewpager opens first and the scroll itself to the (10th) position. I want to open 10th position of viewpager2 directly without scrolling. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried setting the current item as

```
viewPagerReview.currentItem = recyclerviewItemSelectedPosition
```

but if the current item is last position of the recyclerview then viewpager also scrolls till last position.

Comment: Can you please share more of your code please? The problem seems pretty clear; however, it would be much more helpful if you could. There's a method in the `RecyclerView` that scrolls without _smooth scrolling_. You wouldn't see it scroll, it would directly take you to the position you wish.

Comment: Have you tried `recyclerView.layoutManager.scrollToPosition`?

Comment: @Nizar ok, I think my question bit confusing here. Issue is with viewpager2 scroll. I am not scrolling the recyclerview here. need to open viewpager which is on some other activity with the position selected on recycler list.
Thanks for responding quickly.
I have edited my question.

Comment: Actually, you were clear, I wasn't. According to the AndroidWiki `viewpager2` has a default `smoothScroll` when you set `currentItem`. Now my question is, would you consider passing the `selectedPosition` and scrolling to it with the `RecyclerView` or no?

Comment: no, not with the recycler view. just use the position and the list data to viewpager2 directly. Suppose, if the recycler view have 15 items and I click on 10th then viewpager gets opened in another activity and scrolls to the 10th position due to `viewPagerReview.currentItem = recyclerviewItemSelectedPosition` code.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I should have checked the docs before answering. Turns out `viewpager2` does have a method to disable the smooth scrolling.

Comment: recyclerView.layoutManager.scrollToPosition and setting the transition/animation to null is the right way to do it.

Comment: @FaizanTariq how to set transition/animation to null?

Comment: simply set smooth scroll of viewPager to false, it will disable all transition animations for that viewpager.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Alright, according to [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#) on the AndroidDocs, this is what `setCurrentItem(item: Int)` would do:

> Set the currently selected page. If the ViewPager has already been through its first layout with its current adapter there will be a smooth animated transition between the current item and the specified item.

Therefore, you're gonna want to use the other method, which is `setCurrentItem(item: Int, smoothScroll: Boolean)` in order to specify whether you want to `smoothScroll` or not.

So, in your case, go for:

```
viewPagerReview.setCurrentItem(recyclerviewItemSelectedPosition, false)
```

Comment: I'm glad it did @NarendraPal :)

Comment: But this actually does not work reliably. Sometimes it selects the proper page, sometimes not. Probably a race condition in the event driven Android mess. I had to delay it a little bit using the postDelayed() but please note that it is a nasty hack, which does not guarantee it will work on every device :(

Comment: @JiříKřivánek this isn't a hack, this is an actual proper method used. Now the race condition I am not aware. There's a chance that that method might interfere with something else causing this race condition. Is there any way you can share with me a project or some code or a github repo where this happens? If you can, please do... I'd love to see exactly the issue you are facing.

Comment: It wasn't working for me until I updated to `"androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.1.0-alpha01"`

Comment: Same here. Its was reproducably not working at first call. switching to 1.1.0-alpha01 helps

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution for this problem
follow this approach
setCurrentItem(item :Int, smoothScroll : Boolean)
**viewPager.setCurrentItem( 2, false)**